# How to upgrade Matomo from the CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, matomo

I am trying to setup a process to run on the crontab to keep matomo up to date.

I am aware of the `console` cli for matomo, but the `core-update` option says:

`Triggers upgrades. Use it after Matomo core or any plugin files have been updated.`

Does that mean that this option **only** upgrades the database and not the core files of matomo to the latest version?

If so, how can I do that from the command line?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the last version of Matomo first, extract/replace files in your matomo directory and after you will be able to run  `console core:update`.

The command will update the database, not the core files

Comment: php console core:update is working